# Android fingerpaint sample question

Tags: android

I'm checking out the fingerpaint sample in Android SDK http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/graphics/FingerPaint.html

And it works fine but an issue I have is when I rotate the screen the drawable area gets cut off. Anyone know how I can fix this? Thanks a lot.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I was not really familiar with how this site worked. I went ahead and accepted all past answers..Cheers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably not meant to be rotateable. Just set `android:screenOrientation="portrait"` to prevent rotation